# PHP opened article comments pagination

Tags: php, pagination

I want to paginate comments on a opened article - `index.php?article_id=1` and now i want to redirect the page to `index.php?article_id=1&page=2`. I know there is a method to get the current url with get params and just append the &page to it, but every time I click the page button it generates a new get like this: `index.php?article_id=1&page=2&page=2&page=2`...

I have this code, it works only with 1 get param:

```
if($page == $this->maxpages AND $page != 1 OR $page != $this->maxpages AND $page > 0 AND $page <= $this->maxpages AND $page != 1) {
        $controls .= "<a href='".basename(strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'?'))."?p=".($page-1)."'><-- Back </a>";
    }

    if($this->maxpages > 1 AND $page > 0 AND $page != $this->maxpages AND $page < $this->maxpages) {
        $controls .= "<a href='".basename(strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'?'))."?p=".($page+1)."'> Next --></a>";
    }

    if($controls == "" AND $this->maxpages != 1) {
        $controls .= "<a href='".basename(strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'?'))."?p=1'>On the first page</a>";
    }
```

The code that duplicated the get :

```
        if($page == $this->maxpages AND $page != 1 OR $page != $this->maxpages AND $page > 0 AND $page <= $this->maxpages AND $page != 1) {
        $controls .= "<a href='".basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])."&p=".($page-1)."'><-- Back </a>";
    }

    if($this->maxpages > 1 AND $page > 0 AND $page != $this->maxpages AND $page < $this->maxpages) {
        $controls .= "<a href='".basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])."&p=".($page+1)."'> Next --></a>";
    }

    if($controls == "" AND $this->maxpages != 1) {
        $controls .= "<a href='".basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])."&p=1'>First page</a>";
    }
```

Comment: The links you attach to $controls works fine, where is the code that you have written to get the `index.php?article_id=1&page=2&page=2&page=2`?

Comment: The same but without the strtok

Comment: You should add the code you tried to the question.

Comment: Are these options exclusive?  Perhaps you need "else if" instead of just "if" on the latter conditions...

Answer (score 0):

If you use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` you get the whole request. You must create a new URL from the filename and add every parameter you need, changed or the same.

```
$controls .= "<a href='".basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"])."?article_id=" . $articleid . "&p=".($page+1)."'> Next --></a>";
```